# Using org.json.JSONObject in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, org.json

I am trying to use `JSONObject` for a Java application in Eclipse. I have searched everywhere and in every forum. I haven't found a proper answer. Moreover, they keep mentioning a `WEB-INF/lib directory`, which I am not able to find.

I tried adding the `json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar` in the project .jar files. This didn't seem to work either. It shows this error-

> Import org.json.JSONObject cannot be resolved

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, so my answer is equally general...

In order to use a third-party library in Java (like JSON-lib in your case), the library must be present during **compilation** and during **execution** (runtime) of your program. This is done by downloading the `.jar` file and telling Java where to find it. Java uses the concept of **classpath**:

> Classpath is a parameter – set either on the command-line, or through an environment variable – that tells the Java Virtual Machine or the compiler where to look for user-defined classes and packages.

(from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29))

The error you mention ("Import org.json.JSONObject cannot be resolved") means that the `.jar` wasn't on the classpath during compilation.

To add a third-party library in Eclipse, store the `.jar` file somewhere in your project (a dedicated `lib` folder would be a good choice), then right-click on your project, choose Properties → Java Build Path → Libraries, click "Add JARs..." and choose your `.jar` file. From now on, Eclipse will add it to the classpath during compilation.

Adding it to the classpath during execution depends on the kind of project you're running. If you have a simple `main` method which you're running from Eclipse, the `.jar` will be automatically added to the classpath. If you're running a web application in a container such as Tomcat, JBoss etc., then the standard way to add the `.jar` to the classpath would be to put it in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your deployed application. Have a look at the [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) for more information on web applications and their deployment.